# EKS Anywhere timeout on create cluster

Tags: amazon-eks, eksctl

Based on the [EKS Anywhere documentation](https://anywhere.eks.amazonaws.com/docs/getting-started/production-environment/), I built a cluster config yaml. We are using vSphere 7 Enterprise Plus.

When I deploy the cluster with `eksctl anywhere create cluster -f eksa-cluster.yaml`
I get the timeout error below. The error doesn't fall within the timeout error categories of the [Troubleshooting EKS Anywhere documentation page](https://anywhere.eks.amazonaws.com/docs/tasks/troubleshoot/_troubleshooting/#timed-out-waiting-for-the-condition-on-deploymentscapv-controller-manager).

How would I find out the condition on deployments/etcdadm-controller-controller-manager that it is waiting on?

```
Error: failed to create cluster: error waiting for etcdadm-controller-controller-manager in namespace etcdadm-controller-system: 

error executing wait: error: timed out waiting for the condition on deployments/etcdadm-controller-controller-manager
```

Here is the cluster config yaml file.

```
apiVersion: anywhere.eks.amazonaws.com/v1alpha1
kind: Cluster
metadata:
   name: dev-eks-anywhere-cluster
spec:
   clusterNetwork:                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
      cni: "cilium"                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
      pods:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
         cidrBlocks:                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
            - 192.168.0.0/16                                                                                                                                                                                          
      services:                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
         cidrBlocks:                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
            - 10.96.0.0/12                                                                                                                                                                                              
   controlPlaneConfiguration:                                                                                                                                                                                                                
      count: 3 ## see if enough resources are available                                                                                                                                                                                      
      endpoint:                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
         host: "10.91.45.2"                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      machineGroupRef:                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        kind: VSphereMachineConfig                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        name: dev-eks-anywhere-cluster-controller-nodes                                                                                                                                                                                      
   datacenterRef:                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
      kind: VSphereDatacenterConfig                                                                                                                                                                                                          
      name: dev-eks-anywhere-cluster-datacenter                                                                                                                                                                                              
   externalEtcdConfiguration:                                                                                                                                                                                                                
     count: 3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
     machineGroupRef:                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        kind: VSphereMachineConfig                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        name: dev-eks-anywhere-cluster-etcd-nodes                                                                                                                                                                                            
   kubernetesVersion: "1.21"                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
   workerNodeGroupConfigurations:                                                                                                                                                                                                            
   - count: 3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
     machineGroupRef:                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
       kind: VSphereMachineConfig                                                                                                                                                                                                            
       name: dev-eks-anywhere-cluster-worker-nodes                                                                                                                                                                                           

---
apiVersion: anywhere.eks.amazonaws.com/v1alpha1
kind: VSphereDatacenterConfig
metadata:
   name: dev-eks-anywhere-cluster-datacenter
spec:
  datacenter: "REDACTED"
  server: "REDACTED
  network: "K8S_DEV_NET"
  insecure: true
  thumbprint: ""

---
apiVersion: anywhere.eks.amazonaws.com/v1alpha1
kind: VSphereMachineConfig
metadata:
   name: dev-eks-anywhere-cluster-controller-nodes
spec:
  diskGiB: 30
  datastore: "REDACTED"
  folder: ""
  numCPUs: 4
  memoryMiB: 8192
  osFamily: "ubuntu"
  resourcePool: "*/Resources"
  storagePolicyName: ""
  template: "ubuntu-v1.21.2-eks-d-1-21-5-eks-a-2-amd64"
  users:
  - name: "REDACTED"
    sshAuthorizedKeys:
    - "REDACTED"

---
apiVersion: anywhere.eks.amazonaws.com/v1alpha1
kind: VSphereMachineConfig
metadata:
   name: dev-eks-anywhere-cluster-worker-nodes
spec:
  diskGiB: 30
  datastore: "REDACTED"
  folder: ""
  numCPUs: 4
  memoryMiB: 8192
  osFamily: "ubuntu"
  resourcePool: "*/Resources"
  storagePolicyName: ""
  template: "ubuntu-v1.21.2-eks-d-1-21-5-eks-a-2-amd64"
  users:
  - name: "REDACTED"
    sshAuthorizedKeys:
    - "REDACTED"

---
apiVersion: anywhere.eks.amazonaws.com/v1alpha1
kind: VSphereMachineConfig
metadata:
   name: dev-eks-anywhere-cluster-etcd-nodes
spec:
  diskGiB: 30
  datastore: "REDACTED"
  folder: ""
  numCPUs: 4
  memoryMiB: 8192
  osFamily: "ubuntu"
  resourcePool: "*/Resources"
  storagePolicyName: ""
  template: "ubuntu-v1.21.2-eks-d-1-21-5-eks-a-2-amd64"
  users:
  - name: "REDACTED"
    sshAuthorizedKeys:
    - "REDACTED"
```

Comment: can you run the create command with `-v 6` and include log output from the command?

Comment: Did it deploy any etcd vms on vSphere? Did it deploy any vms at all on vSphere?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the kind cluster created on your admin machine?

> kubectl get machines -A

If you see machines under provisioning, now check the deployment status on baremetal. Check the number of containers running and logs for each container.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).